# How to use colours in console output in Scala or Java?

Tags: java, scala, colors, console-application

How to use colours in console output in Scala or Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sample code from [JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-12/02-qa-1220-console.html)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import enigma.console.*;
import enigma.core.Enigma;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TextAttributes attrs = new TextAttributes(Color.BLUE, Color.WHITE);
        s_console.setTextAttributes(attrs);
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
    private static final Console s_console;
    static
    {
        s_console = Enigma.getConsole("Hellow World!");
    }
}
```

Visit the above link for more details and approaches.

Answer (score 28):

Try...

```
scala> Console.BLUE
res0: java.lang.String =
```

OK, well, the text has gone blue. Honest!

```
scala> Console.YELLOW_B
res2: java.lang.String =
```

And you can see the background is, um, yellow.

Answer (score 15):

Just to extend the answer from oxbow_lakes: in scala 2.9.2 interpreter I had to explicitly print the BLUE string:

```
scala> println(Console.BLUE + " now it's really blue!")
```